# Store 2 values in one variable

Tags: go, binary, bit-shift, bit

Is this Go code correct and portable, I need to store 2 counters (each call only one counter will be updated) in one variable to avoid locks in actual code where I am going to use single atomic.AddUint64() instead of locking whole struct.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var long uint64 // Actual counters storage

func main() {
    left := uint32(100) // First counter
    right := uint32(200) // Second counter
    long = uint64(left)
    long = long << 32 | uint64(right)
    fmt.Println(left, right)

    long += uint64(1 << 32) // Increment left
    long += 1 // Increment right

    xLeft := uint32(long >> 32) // Get left
    xRight := uint32(long) // Get right
    fmt.Println(xLeft, xRight)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/aBlp-Zatgn

Comment: This might be a better question for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Depending on the actual read/write access paterns this may not get you anything over the simpler code using two `uint32`'s and `atomic.AddUint32`. Make sure that other than initialization **all** access to such a counter is done only via `atomic.LoadUint64` and other atomic functions.

Comment: There was an answer (now deleted) that wrapped this in functions [with a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391141/store-2-values-in-one-variable#comment48877000_30392396) by @thwd suggesting doing it as a type with methods. Possibly something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/hjhs_6061n (although personally I doubt I'd use such a thing).

Comment: The idea is to get consistent state of 2 counters atomically, this is why I used 1 variable for both counters, atomic.Add* will change and return consistent state of both values stored in this variable. My requirements changed, I have to reset both counters to 0 if their sum = N and it's impossible with single atomic op, only by 2 sequential calls (incr one, compare, reset if sum >= N) and this is not consistent. So I am going to end up with locks. Deleted answer was great beside it is not what I asked, I used almost the same code. Also combined type with method is great suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this Go code correct and portable

It is correct, as long as you work with unsigned integers of 64-bit width.

Portability in this case is provided by the `sync/atomic` packages to the architectures supported by the Go compiler. Note, however, that not all architectures support "true" atomic operations on 64-bit wide data. For example, [the i386 implementation](http://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/asm_386.s#L113) uses a CAS-loop:

```
TEXT ·AddUint64(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-20
    // no XADDQ so use CMPXCHG8B loop
    MOVL    addr+0(FP), BP
    TESTL   $7, BP
    JZ  2(PC)
    MOVL    0, AX // crash with nil ptr deref
    // DI:SI = delta
    MOVL    delta_lo+4(FP), SI
    MOVL    delta_hi+8(FP), DI
    // DX:AX = *addr
    MOVL    0(BP), AX
    MOVL    4(BP), DX
addloop:
    // CX:BX = DX:AX (*addr) + DI:SI (delta)
    MOVL    AX, BX
    MOVL    DX, CX
    ADDL    SI, BX
    ADCL    DI, CX

    // if *addr == DX:AX {
    //  *addr = CX:BX
    // } else {
    //  DX:AX = *addr
    // }
    // all in one instruction
    LOCK
    CMPXCHG8B   0(BP)

    JNZ addloop

    // success
    // return CX:BX
    MOVL    BX, new_lo+12(FP)
    MOVL    CX, new_hi+16(FP)
    RET
```

That may open the question: why not use a struct with a lock?

---

Edit to answer question in comments: Yes, using a 32-bit integer would result in actual atomic operations on all Go-supported architectures because they all support `XADDL` (or analog) to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I can even downgrade to uint32 and uint16 and even low because actually i don't such big capacity for both counters. Can I avoid CAS-loop in this case?

Comment: And also, this is mostly for educational purposes, I didn't perform performance tests with locks and atomic ops. I believe it's just efficient, but "believe" is a word that should not be used in software engineering.